# Check for empty file and quit cakebuild

Tags: cakebuild

I am attempting to write a check in my Cake build script to pull in a file from `BuildParameters` and check if the file contents are empty -- if contents are empty, throw an exception and quit the build.

I am attempting to use `FileReadText` from the `FileHelpers` namespace but for some reason I cannot get my build to recognize the file command. I am following the syntax and documentation found here: https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.FileHelpers/FileHelperAliases/97F5679A

Here is the code I am trying in `build.cake`:

```
var fileReadText= FileReadText(Parameters.TestParameters.TestListFP);
var fileText= fileReadText.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(nameof(fileReadText));
```

The argument `Parameters.TestParameters.TestListFP` is set in my `Parameters.cake` file as such:

```
TestListFP = context.File("C:\Some\Path\some_file_name.txt");
```

Using the above code, I see this error:

> error CS0103: The name 'FileReadText' does not exist in the current 
>   context

Note that I do not have a `ICakeContext` in `build.cake`, just `BuildParameters`.

I tried to resolve the issue by adding `using Cake.FileHelpers;` at the top of my `build.cake` file, but then I see this error:

> The type or namespace name 'FileHelpers' does not exist in the namespace 'Cake' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The script works fine without my `FileReadText` code, so I know `TestListFP` is actually a valid file.

I think I am inherently misunderstanding how to use `FileHelpers` and `FileReadText` and I could not find any examples of usage in documentation or anywhere else. If anyone has guidance on how to use this method, or a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: as an alternative option you can use `FileSize` to check if the file size is more than 0 bytes: https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.IO/FileAliases/E35F243B It's from `Cake.Common.IO` namespace, so you don't need to use any addins to be able to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the #addin pre-processor directive, as mentioned here:

https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.FileHelpers/#cakefilehelpers

> You can easily reference Cake.FileHelpers directly in your build script via a cake addin:
>
> `#addin "Cake.FileHelpers"`

Comment: This worked for me, and it also helped me solve my other issue with `ThrowIfNullOrEmpty` and the `Cake.Incubator` addin. Thanks for your help!